# how use enclosing shortcodes in php ( wordpress theme )

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

edd restrict content plugin creates this shortcodes and these are working in pages and posts :

```
[edd_restrict id="any"]sample restricted html or text[/edd_restrict]
```

but i want to use it in my theme not in the posts or pages.
i tried this :

```
<?php =echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]' . sample text . '[/edd_restrict]' );?>
```

but theme shows me fatal error.
so how can i use this shortcodes in wordress theme?
sample text here will be a php code that i want to restrict.

---

let me tell you more... i want to put the line below between those shortcodes in my single.php in wordpress :

```
<li><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' > دانلود با لینک مستقیم</a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)."'>لینک مستقیم نسخه 32bit / </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?> 
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download64',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download64',true)."'>لینک مستقیم نسخه 64bit </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'downloadwin',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'downloadwin',true)."'>دانلود نسخه ویندوز  </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?></li>
```

Comment: If that is the exact code you use then it's wrong syntax. For first remove the `=` at the beginning

Comment: i did that. again fatal error.
you know what i need.
there is a function for paid membership pro for php or html restriction like this :
<?php
if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel(array('12','14','Gold')))
{
?>
//Place your HTML or PHP code here if the user is in the required membership level
...
<?php 
}
?>

i need something like this for restricting php with edd restriction content . but edd just have shortcodes not php function.

Comment: Well, what is the fatal error? did you replace "sample text" with a valid string?

Comment: i replaced sample text with this for example :
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]'
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/post-ads.php");?>
'[/edd_restrict]' );?>

Comment: or i did this :

<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]'
<br><li> password : <a href="https://www.example.com">www.example.com</a></li>
'[/edd_restrict]' );?>

again fatal error

Answer (score 0):

The method [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) accepts a string of a shortcode and it's attributes/content. So for example

```php
<?php

$string = "some value or <b>html</b>";
// or (?)
$string = include TEMPLATEPATH . "/post-ads.php";
// or (!)
ob_start();
include TEMPLATEPATH . "/post-ads.php";
$string = ob_get_clean();

// for a specific use case:
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download', true) != "") {
    $string = "<a href='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download', true) . "' >download</a> ";
} else {
    $string = "";
}
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32', true) != "") {
    $string2 = "<a href='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32', true) . "'>download 32bit / </a> ";
} else {
    $string2 = "";
}

// after you have string:
echo do_shortcode('[edd_restrict id="any"]' . $string . '[/edd_restrict]');
```

Comment: you mean string in here is what i put between shortcodes in a page?
so can you tell me about this php and how should i put this php betwen this shortcoed :

<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' >download</a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)."'>download 32bit / </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>

Comment: or can i put the DIV between it?
this div for example :

<div class="dl">
<ul>
<li><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download',true)."' > download</a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)!= ""){echo "<a href='".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download32',true)."'>download 32bit / </a> ";} else { echo ""; } ?>

Comment: i put the code you said in themplate but again fatal error...

Comment: sorry bro i edited main question can you help me with that?

Comment: But did this answer work for you?

Comment: i can not use those codes. i used first code you said for "TEMPLATEPATH . "/post-ads.php" and get fatal error again. so if you edit the codes just for main question i can try them.

Comment: you know what i want? look at this : 
https://easydigitaldownloads.com/docs/content-restriction-documentation/
there is just : Restricting the full page / post and shortcodes 
but i want restrict part of php in my template whis is custom fields as you know.
so it can be 2 way to do it. first is restricting php in my template and second is somhow restricting custom fields in wordpress with edd

Comment: yes again fatal error occurs.

Comment: i checked this :
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample php[/edd_restrict]' );?>
this work in the theme but just for text or html not for php comands...

Comment: Good. but you can generate html as string in the php - right before you echo do_shortcode

Comment: i dont understand what you sayin... i dont want use html i want put php as i said befor instead of sample text in this : <?php echo do_shortcode( '[edd_restrict id="any"]sample text[/edd_restrict]' );?>